# Centos 7, Vagrant with Virtualbox - Apache virtual hosts working on guest machine, on host showing "it works"

Tags: apache, centos, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have setup a working Centos 7 Apache virtual host website in vagrant with virtualbox configured with a mapped static ip address and shared folders (192.168.88.1).

when I ssh into the guest machine with the vagrant user (I have port forwarding working as well for ssh), I can curl the website and it returns the correct html.

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
curl localsite.dev
```

If I do the same thing and curl the direct static ip address, it also returns the correct html

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
curl 192.168.88.1
```

When I access this site or ip address from the host machine from a browser the response is "It Works". I'm not sure where to start, because the logs are empty, it's obviously loading the correct server and the ping results are all successful. I'm not sure what code to post on here, because I'm confused as to what could cause this. I've followed like 100 guides, even line for line and it still doesn't work). Any ideas or where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added port forwarding to the NAT card (8080 host port - 80 guest port) in the Network settings for the virtual machine. Then in the hosts file I setup the domain to point to 192.168.88.1 and in the browser I put in the address localsite.dev:8080 and finally it does load the site.